# Create Initial Push into Newly Created Repository using VSTS Git API

Tags: c#, git, azure-devops

How to create initial push into newly created Repository using VSTS Git API?

I have created a new repository.

```
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebApi;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Core.WebApi

var accountUri = new Uri("https://mysite.visualstudio.com");  
var personalAccessToken = "myaccesstoken"; 
var connection = new VssConnection(accountUri, new VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, personalAccessToken));

// Get a GitHttpClient to talk to the Git endpoints
var gitClient = connection.GetClient<GitHttpClient>();

var teamProject = projectClient.GetProject("MyProject", true, true).Result;

var repo = gitClient.CreateRepositoryAsync(new GitRepository
{
    DefaultBranch = "refs/heads/master",
    Name = "TestRepo",
    ProjectReference = new TeamProjectReference
    {
        Id = teamProject.Id
    }
}).Result;
```

The repo is successfully created. But why is the `repo.DefaultBranch` value is null?

Next step, I'd like to push my initial commit.

```
var newBranch = new GitRefUpdate
{
    RepositoryId = repo.Id,
    Name = $"refs/heads/master"
};

string newFileName = "README.md";
GitCommitRef newCommit = new GitCommitRef
{
    Comment = "Initial commit",
    Changes = new GitChange[]
    {
        new GitChange
        {
            ChangeType = VersionControlChangeType.Add,
            Item = new GitItem { Path = $"/master/{newFileName}" },
            NewContent = new ItemContent
            {
                Content = "# Thank you for using VSTS!",
                ContentType = ItemContentType.RawText,
            },
        }
    }
};

GitPush push = gitClient.CreatePushAsync(new GitPush
{
    RefUpdates = new GitRefUpdate[] { newBranch },
    Commits = new GitCommitRef[] { newCommit },
}, repo.Id).Result;
```

I got an error when calling `CreatePushAsync`:

> VssServiceException: The combination of parameters is either not valid
>   or not complete. Parameter name: baseCommitId

Please help how to create initial commit properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the rest api to achieve what you want. The rest api of [creating an initial commit (create a new branch)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/git/pushes/create?view=vsts-rest-4.1#initial_commit_(create_a_new_branch)) is as below:

```
POST https://fabrikam.visualstudio.com/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/pushes?api-version=4.1

{
  "refUpdates": [
    {
      "name": "refs/heads/master",
      "oldObjectId": "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
    }
  ],
  "commits": [
    {
      "comment": "Initial commit.",
      "changes": [
        {
          "changeType": "add",
          "item": {
            "path": "/readme.md"
          },
          "newContent": {
            "content": "My first file!",
            "contentType": "rawtext"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you.
I missed initialize the `OldObjectId` to `0000000000000000000000000000000000000000`.

Comment: That does not answer the question.... Consider if a new repo (blank) is created. Perhaps it uses "master", perhaps "main", perhaps "trunk"...   How do we determine that since the property is blank?!?!?!?